# Laravel 4.0 Daily limit on button function

Tags: mysql, laravel, limit

what is the best way to limit user to use the button 2 times per day(disable the button) or to reset the function for example at 6 AM with out using Cron Mysql?

Answer (score 0):

- Put a counter of the user clicks on that button.
- When the button is pressed, detect current time and proceed as desired